# awk: end of line vs end of record

Tags: awk, paragraph, stanza

I am trying to match number at the end of the line ($), print relevant paragraphs and ignore third paragraph. Here is data:

```
this is first paragraph
number 200
with some text

this is second paragraph
with some text
number 200

this is third paragraph
with some text
number 2001
```

This command matches only first paragraph:
`awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" "/number 200\n/" file`

This command matches only second paragraph:
`awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" "/number 200$/" file`

Seems the problem is that awk understands character "$" as end of record instead of line. Is there some elegant way how to overcome this? Unfortunately I do not have grep that can work with paragraphs.

**UPDATE:**

Expected output:

```
this is first paragraph
number 200
with some text

this is second paragraph
with some text
number 200
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Yes, `$` is end of record (and `^` is beginning of record). I don't know if you count it as elegant, but you can match `/number 200(\n|$)/`

Comment: @Cyrus I've added the sample.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 seems my brain did not work properly during night because I haven't realized that it is actually normal regex. Now I read that AWK does support extended regex. Thank you for pointing me the direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/(^|\n)number 200(\n|$)/' file
this is first paragraph
number 200
with some text

this is second paragraph
with some text
number 200
```

Regarding `Seems the problem is that awk understands character "$" as end of record instead of line` - that's not a problem, that's the definition of `$`. In a regexp `$` means `end of string`, it only appears to mean `end of line` if the string you're matching against just happens to be a single line, e.g. as read by grep, sed, and awk by default. When you're matching against a string containing multiple lines (e.g. using `-z` in GNU grep or GNU sed or `RS=""` in awk or `RS='^$'` in GNU awk) then you should expect `$` to match just once at the and of that string (and `^` just once at the start of it), there's nothing special about newlines versus any other character in the string and no regexp metachar to match them.

Regarding `Unfortunately I do not have grep that can work with paragraphs` - no-one does as, unlike awk, grep doesn't have a paragraph mode.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the desired output in your question.

However, if I understand you may want record 1 & 2 but not 3:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '{s=$0; gsub("\n", " ", s); if (s ~ /number 200( |$)/) print}' file
```

Comment: Yes 1 & 2 but not 3. Can you please explain how come that the blank space matches "end of record"? Is new line character also considered as a white space?